# How to expand a tree row on whole row click in tree-grid-directive?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, treegrid

I am using [tree-grid-directive](https://github.com/khan4019/tree-grid-directive/blob/master/README.md). At present the row expands on click of icons and not the whole row, is there a way available to expand row on whole row click itself?

```
<tree-grid
  expand-level  = "3"
  tree-data     = "tree_data"
  expand-on     = "expanding_property"
  col-defs      = "col_defs"
  icon-leaf     = "glyphicon glyphicon-file"
  icon-expand   = "glyphicon glyphicon-folder-close"
  icon-collapse = "glyphicon glyphicon-folder-open">
</tree-grid>
```

Here is a [plunker example](http://plnkr.co/edit/EHiac00KHzGMSFjAWjCK?p=preview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try move the **ng-click** inside the *i* element

```
ng-click=\"row.branch.expanded = !row.branch.expanded\"\
```

to the parent *td* element.

```
<tr ng-repeat=\"row in tree_rows | filter:{visible:true} track by row.branch.uid\"\
    ng-click=\"row.branch.expanded = !row.branch.expanded\"\
    ng-class=\"'level-' + {{ row.level }} + (row.branch.selected ? ' active':'')\" class=\"tree-grid-row\">\
```

Here is the plunker updated: http://plnkr.co/edit/yfU1zmkRXjrZwJAG5PS4?p=preview